# karate gatling's maxDuration does not appear to be working correctly

Tags: karate

I'm running a simulation with 4 feature files, SIM_ACTIVE_USERS=200, SIM_RAMP_UP_PERIOD=10. I am expecting the simulation to finish in 10 seconds with the code below:

```
class TestGatlingScalaSimulation extends Simulation {

  val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[TestGatlingScalaSimulation])

  /*val environmentVars = System.getenv().asScala
  for ((k,v) <- environmentVars) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")*/

  val properties: mutable.Map[String, String] = System.getProperties.asScala
  //for ((k,v) <- properties) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")
  val activeUsers: Int = properties.getOrElse("SIM_ACTIVE_USERS", "10").asInstanceOf[String].toInt
  val period: Int = properties.getOrElse("SIM_RAMP_UP_PERIOD", "10").asInstanceOf[String].toInt
  val karateFeatureFiles: List[String] = properties.getOrElse("SIM_FEATURE", "karate/example.feature").split(",").map(_.trim).toList

  val protocol: KarateProtocol = karateProtocol()

  protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")

  val scenarios: List[PopulationBuilder] = karateFeatureFiles.map(karateFeatureFile => {
    val create: ScenarioBuilder = scenario(karateFeatureFile).exec(karateFeature(s"classpath:$karateFeatureFile"))
    log.info("Running simulation of feature [{}] with [{}] users ramped up in [{}]", karateFeatureFile, activeUsers.toString, period.toString)
    create.inject(atOnceUsers(activeUsers)).protocols(protocol)
  })

  setUp(
    scenarios
  ).maxDuration(period seconds)
}
```

However it only finishes in 7 minutes:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7m 0s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

This is how I run the gradle task:

```
./gradlew -Pgatling_simulation=performance.TestGatlingScalaSimulation -DSIM_ACTIVE_USERS=200 -DSIM_RAMP
_UP_PERIOD=10 -DSIM_FEATURE="karate/flight/one.feature,karate/flight/two.feature,karate/flight/three.feature,kara
te/flight/four.feature" gatlingRun
```

The report from gatling:
[image]

Comment: this is the kind of issue we really need a way to replicate. so can you follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - for a good example of someone who helped us fix something in the past, see this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/845#issuecomment-515209563

Comment: @PeterThomas I tried to reproduce without success so far. I notice there isn’t a way to control precise requests / s.

Comment: you meed to be more precise :) but seriously, most teams don’t need precision when generating load

Comment: Yes you are right, I’m looking at bringing the requests up probably to 10X the load you see in the above attached graph. But I notice setting a 10X more no. of users does not bring the load up.

Comment: ok, do keep trying to replicate. but maybe you are simply hitting resource limits for your hardware / os

Comment: I'm not sure if its a resource issue, I tried to replicate by hitting a server on localhost instead. The reports seem to show the right thing of climbing to 1000+ users. See my example - https://github.com/geekyme/karate/blob/a50296dfd7c0a8fd2a56fe835f918d41f84d0ab6/examples/gatling/BUG.md

It only didn't seem to work when I'm hitting a remote API, connecting through a VPN.

Comment: well, that certainly sounds like your network is set up to throttle requests :) this is normal in corporate setups. work with your ops folks !

Comment: However I’m able to make a huge amount of requests to the same remote endpoints through jmeter though. So I’m not sure if there’s an implementation detail I miss in Gatling setup.

Comment: It is quite likely that JMeter is incorrect http://highscalability.com/blog/2015/10/5/your-load-generator-is-probably-lying-to-you-take-the-red-pi.html - anyway I give up. try to create a pure-gatling test, and if that looks different - give us a way to replicate and then we will be in business